# Trying to Update Pose of HectorSLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, pose, hector, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am using hector mapping and it works kind of good. I want to synchronize the map with some other tool and I would like to know:
How can I delete/reset/restart the map which is created by hector mapping
How can I set the inital pose of hector mapping for example it is not (0,0,0) it is (13,21,5)

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212666/trying-to-update-pose-of-hectorslam/) by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2015-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The clearing question I already answered [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/212751/clear-map-from-hectormapping/).

The estimated pose can be moved by publishing to the "/initialpose" topic just how it is done for AMCL. The easiest option is to just use the "2D Pose Estimate" button in rviz. Currently, this does not automatically reset the map however.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on 2015-07-02**:
thank you!